# To check if user Is Logged in or not

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using `SharedPreferences` to check if user is logged  in or not.
If the user is not logged in, he will be taken to login activity (or) my info activity.

My code is as follows.

This is in login activity.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putBoolean("logged", true); // set it to false when the user is logged out
editor.commit(); // Commit the edits!
```

I have checking code in the main activity which looks as follows

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean loggedIn = settings.getBoolean("logged", true);
if (loggedIn != true) {
    // Toast.makeText(this,"you are logged in !!",3000).show();
    /* Intent i = new Intent(this,Login.class);
     startActivity(i);*/
    Intent intent = new
    Intent(MymainScreen.this, Registered.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // Toast.makeText(this,"you are not logged in !!",3000).show();
    Intent intent = new
    Intent(MymainScreen.this, My_info.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Please help me with this, I am not able to develop further without this activity.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you want to check the login state with using `SharedPreferences`, by default you should think user is logged out. So, when nothing in `SharedPreferences`, you should take default value equals to `false` not `true`.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
Intent intent = null;
if (prefs.getBoolean("logged_in", false)) { //user logged in before
    intent = new Intent(this, Info.class);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
}

startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Its taking only one condition, Its not setting the status.I have put my putboolean method in onclick method in under login bitton